# Correspondence between flat connections and fundamental group representations

Tags: differential-geometry, fundamental-groups, principal-bundles, holonomy

Let $M$ be a manifold.
Two stackexchange posts state that there is a correspondence
$$
\{
(P,A):
P \text{ a $G$-bundle}, A \text{ flat connection}
\}
\leftrightarrow
\{
\text{morphisms }
f:\pi_1(M) \rightarrow G
\},
$$
namely [Recovering a principal connection from its monodromy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737717/recovering-a-principal-connection-from-its-monodromy) and [Are vector bundles given by their monodromy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673675/are-vector-bundles-given-by-their-monodromy).

I believe that the correspondence is given by
$$
(P,A)
\mapsto f,
$$
where $f([\gamma])=g$, where $g$ denotes the element such that $\gamma^*(0)g=\gamma^*(1)$.
Here $\gamma^*$ denotes a horizontal lift of $\gamma$.
This is well defined by flatness of $A$.

If $\pi_1(M)$ is a free group, I understand why the correspondence is 1-to-1.
That is because to define a $G$-bundle on $M$ I need to specify precisely an element in $G$ for each loop in $\pi_1(M)$, that is the idea mentioned in the accepted answer of the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4138/why-are-local-systems-on-a-complex-analytic-space-equivalent-to-vector-bundles-w?noredirect=1&lq=1.

> Why is this correspondence 1-to-1 in general?
>   Can you point me to a reference which contains the proof?

Comment: This has been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419456/representation-of-fundamental-group-and-flat-connections